# Fastest way to call two functions multiple times without using a list of input parameters

Tags: python-3.x, performance, image-processing, multiprocessing

I have written a small programm that uses a pipe.

The parent takes care of camera connection while the child is processing the images.

The child process calls two functions FunctionA and FunctionB. Both times the image from the parent is processed.

I want to run the two functions as fast as possible since they are time consuming 0.1s, 0.12s. I tried multiprocessing.Processes and multiprocessing.pools. The bottle neck in the first case is the creation of the two processes for each image passed by the parent. Pools only make sense if I would have a list of images which I cant wait for since the speed up from the pipe will be wasted which is already quite good -3.123 seconds. Does somebody has a smart solution for this sort of problem?

Kind regards :)

Example code:

```
import multiprocessing
import cv2
import glob 
import cv2
from multiprocessing import pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import glob
import time 
from ProcA import FunctionA
from ProcB import FunctionB
import Lines
import Feature
#===============================================================================
# Test Pipe
```

#===============================================================================

```
def cam_loop(pipe_parent):
    imagePathes = glob.glob("Images\*.jpg")
    for path in imagePathes:
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        pipe_parent.send(image)
        StringFromChild = pipe_parent.recv()
        print("StringFromChild:",StringFromChild)


def show_loop(pipe_child):
    #cv2.namedWindow('pepe')
    proc = Preprocessor.Preprocessor()
    line = Lines.Lines()
    features = Feature.FeatureDetector()
    imgIdx = 0
    Q_Barcode = multiprocessing.Queue(10)
    Q_CapFeatures = multiprocessing.Queue(100)

    while True:
        image = pipe_child.recv()

        start = time.time()
        #Calculating features
        #Create processes
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = FunctionA, args = (proc, image, imgIdx, None, None, None,))
        p1.start()

        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = FunctionB, args = (line, proc, features, image, imgIdx,))
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        #send features calculated to parent
        pipe_child.send("OK")
        end = time.time()
        print("TimeMultiProc",end - start)

        start = time.time()

        #Calculating feature
        FunctionA(proc, image, imgIdx, None, None, None)
        FunctionB(line, proc, features, image, imgIdx)

        #send features calculated to parent
        end = time.time()
        print("TimeSerial",end - start)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)

    pipe_parent, pipe_child = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    cam_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=cam_loop,args=(pipe_parent, ))
    cam_process.start()

    show_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=show_loop,args=(pipe_child, ))
    show_process.start()

    cam_process.join()
    show_loop.join()
```